# How to understand the second fundamental form is Tensorial?

Tags: differential-geometry

From wikipedia. The second fundamental form is defined by 
$$II(u,\ v)=\left \langle \nabla_u v,\ n  \right \rangle$$ 
where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection of the ambient manifold $M$, and $u, v$ are tengent vectors of the sumbmanifold $N$. Lets assume the codimension of $N$ is $1$, so the $n$ here is the unit normal vector of $N$ in $M$.

The tensorial says that $II(u,\ v)$ does not depends extensions of $u, v$?
Is it true that the extensions of $u,v$ must still be a tangent vector fields of $N$?
or any extension?
I guess it is the first case, otherwise it would not make any sense that $II$ described how $N$ curved in $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're completely right. In order to make sense of the l.h.s. of the expression $\langle \nabla_u v , n \rangle$, at a point $p \in M$, say, you have to pick vector fields $U, V$ (on $M$) with $U(p) = u$ and $V(p) = v$, then evaluate $\langle \nabla_U V , n \rangle$ at $p$. Being tensorial now means that the expression $\langle \nabla_U V , n \rangle (p)$ does not depend on the particular vector fields chosen but only on the values of $U$ and $V$ at $p$ (i.e. $u$ and $v$). So we can define the second fundamental form as a family of maps 
$$
II_p : T_pM \times T_pM \to \mathbb{R}
$$ 
by picking arbitrary extensions as described above.